# Is non-stick aluminum foil safe to use on the grill?

Tags: food-safety, grilling, non-stick, aluminum-foil, foil-cooking

Is non-stick aluminum foil safe to use on the grill? My personal grill is propane.

I'm concerned that using this for a foil packet style of cooking will heat the non-stick so hot that it degrades. Not sure if the non-stick coating would be problematic from a flavor or health concern in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what a "non stick aluminum foil" is, something like [this](https://www.reynoldskitchens.com/products/aluminum-foil/non-stick-foil/)?

> Whether in the oven, **on the grill or anywhere in between**, Reynolds Wrap® Non-Stick Foil gets the job done anytime and anywhere. You can cook, cover, freeze and store with ease.

Usually, when using aluminum packets, we cook them on an indirect flame.

If your grill has 2 burners, you close one up and keep the other one open and put the packets on the closed burner side.

It'll act more or less like a regular oven.

The link above says that it [can be used](https://www.reynoldskitchens.com/tips/grilled-flavor-infused-foil-packets/) (with a link to recipes) for grilling.

Comment: Yes, exactly the linked product.